Clarifying Lagrange Multipliers in Maximum Entropy Distribution for Mean and Variance Constraints
I am deriving the maximum entropy distribution under the constraints of mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. The general form of the maximum entropy distribution is:
$$
f(x) = \exp\left( -1 - \lambda_0 - \lambda_1 x - \lambda_2 x^2 \right)
$$
The three conditions I'm working with are:

Normalization:
$$
   \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp\left( -1 - \lambda_0 - \lambda_1 x - \lambda_2 x^2 \right) dx = 1
   $$

Mean:
$$
   \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x \exp\left( -1 - \lambda_0 - \lambda_1 x - \lambda_2 x^2 \right) dx = \mu
   $$

Variance:
$$
   \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2 \exp\left( -1 - \lambda_0 - \lambda_1 x - \lambda_2 x^2 \right) dx = \mu^2 + \sigma^2
   $$


For the fist one, I obtained:
$\lambda_0 = -1 - \frac{1}{2} \log(\pi) + \frac{1}{2} \log(\lambda_2) + \frac{\lambda_1^2}{4 \lambda_2} $
I am having trouble simplifying the expression for $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$. Could someone explain how to solve for $\lambda_1$ and  $\lambda_2$

"The general form of the maximum entropy distribution is" That seems wrong. You are supposed to conclude that fact, not to assume it. (and it's not "the general form", it's only when you are given the mean and variance)
